# Spring get FactoryBean property

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

In Spring, you can get a reference to a FactoryBean using the following syntax:

```
<constructor-arg ref="&amp;factoryBean" />
```

This is necessary because if you reference the FactoryBean without the & you will simply get an instance of a bean that the factory produces.

In Spring, you can get a reference to a Bean Property using the following syntax:

```
<constructor-arg ref="bean.propertyName" />
```

Now what I need to do is to combine these tactics to get a bean property from a FactoryBean. 
I have tried the following syntax with no success:

```
<constructor-arg ref="&amp;factoryBean.propertyName" />
```

The above syntax does not work because Spring attempts to reference a bean with the name factoryBean.propertyName

Comment: are you sure you mean beanfactory? or factorybean?

Comment: @NathanHughes, you are correct, I meant factorybean.